# htaccess rewrites not working on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

While there are many similar posts, I have read them all to no avail.  Let me describe my situation in hopes that someone can resolve this issue.  I have the following .htaccess file living in /Users/myusername/Sites/domain.com/public_html/.htaccess.  The DocumentRoot is set to /Users/myusername/Sites/domain.com/public_html.

```
RewriteEngine on
options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /demo 
RewriteRule ^/demo/evaluate/1$ /demo/evaluate/index.php?eval_id=1 [L]
```

Now for the settings:

1. "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" in httpd.conf is uncommented.
2. "AllowOverride All" everywhere

The htaccess redirects work, but for some reason I just keep getting the following error in my error logs:

```
[Sun Apr 22 11:14:09 2012] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Users/myusername/Sites/domain.com/public_html/demo/evaluate/1
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

---

Honestly, not sure what happened.  I did not change anything.

It could have been some magic combination of all of the settings and feedback.  But now it is working.  It's like a house of cards that I am just going to step back from and marvel at until I accidentally break it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/evaluate/1$ demo/evaluate/index.php?eval_id=1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check these two lines and check

```
RewriteBase /demo 
RewriteRule ^/demo/evaluate/$1 /demo/evaluate/index.php?eval_id=$1 [L]
```